# d3.v5.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently studying on how to create a pie-chart with a legend. But the thing is while i'm trying to re-code the program I encountered this error:

[image]

As per checking the code error: `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);` i don't know why this became an error since it's usually working.

The code snippet is my code below:

```js
// define data
var dataset = [
    {label: "Assamese", count: 100},
    {label: "Bengali", count: 83},
    {label: "Bodo", count: 1.4},
    {label: "Dogri", count: 2.3},
    {label: "Gujarati", count: 46},
    {label: "Hindi", count: 300},
    {label: "Kannada", count: 38},
    {label: "Kashmiri", count: 5.5},
    {label: "Konkani", count: 5},
    {label: "Maithili", count: 20},
    {label: "Malayalam", count: 33},
    {label: "Manipuri", count: 1.5},
    {label: "Marathi", count: 72},
    {label: "Nepali", count: 2.9},
    {label: "Oriya", count: 33},
    {label: "Punjabi", count: 29},
    {label: "Sanskrit", count: 0.01},
    {label: "Santhali", count: 6.5},
    {label: "Sindhi", count: 2.5},
    {label: "Tamil", count: 61},
    {label: "Telugu", count: 74},
    {label: "Urdu", count: 52}
  ];

// chart dimensions
var width = 1200;
var height = 800;

// a circle chart needs a radius
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// legend dimensions
var legendRectSize = 25; // defines the size of the colored squares in legend
var legendSpacing = 6; // defines spacing between squares

// define color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
// more color scales: https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/3393ff2711a53975040077b7453781a9

var svg = d3.select('#pieChart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('svg') // append an svg element to the element we've selected
  .attr('width', width) // set the width of the svg element we just added
  .attr('height', height) // set the height of the svg element we just added
  .append('g') // append 'g' element to the svg element
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); // our reference is now to the 'g' element. centerting the 'g' element to the svg element

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0) // none for pie chart
  .outerRadius(radius); // size of overall chart

var pie = d3.pie() // start and end angles of the segments
  .value(function(d) { return d.count; }) // how to extract the numerical data from each entry in our dataset
  .sort(null); // by default, data sorts in oescending value. this will mess with our animation so we set it to null

// define tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select('#pieChart') // select element in the DOM with id 'chart'
  .append('div') // append a div element to the element we've selected                                    
  .attr('class', 'tooltip'); // add class 'tooltip' on the divs we just selected

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                            
  .attr('class', 'label'); // add class 'label' on the selection                         

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above                     
  .attr('class', 'count'); // add class 'count' on the selection                  

tooltip.append('div') // add divs to the tooltip defined above  
  .attr('class', 'percent'); // add class 'percent' on the selection

// Confused? see below:

// <div id="chart">
//   <div class="tooltip">
//     <div class="label">
//     </div>
//     <div class="count">
//     </div>
//     <div class="percent">
//     </div>
//   </div>
// </div>

dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  d.count = +d.count; // calculate count as we iterate through the data
  d.enabled = true; // add enabled property to track which entries are checked
});

// creating the chart
var path = svg.selectAll('path') // select all path elements inside the svg. specifically the 'g' element. they don't exist yet but they will be created below
  .data(pie(dataset)) //associate dataset wit he path elements we're about to create. must pass through the pie function. it magically knows how to extract values and bakes it into the pie
  .enter() //creates placeholder nodes for each of the values
  .append('path') // replace placeholders with path elements
  .attr('d', arc) // define d attribute with arc function above
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.label); }) // use color scale to define fill of each label in dataset
  .each(function(d) { this._current - d; }); // creates a smooth animation for each track

// mouse event handlers are attached to path so they need to come after its definition
path.on('mouseover', function(d) {  // when mouse enters div      
 var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // calculate the total number of tickets in the dataset         
  return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // checking to see if the entry is enabled. if it isn't, we return 0 and cause other percentages to increase                                      
  }));                                                      
 var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10; // calculate percent
 tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label); // set current label           
 tooltip.select('.count').html('$' + d.data.count); // set current count            
 tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%'); // set percent calculated above          
 tooltip.style('display', 'block'); // set display                     
});                                                           

path.on('mouseout', function() { // when mouse leaves div                        
  tooltip.style('display', 'none'); // hide tooltip for that element
 });

path.on('mousemove', function(d) { // when mouse moves                  
  tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px') // always 10px below the cursor
    .style('left', (d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px'); // always 10px to the right of the mouse
  });

// define legend
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // selecting elements with class 'legend'
  .data(color.domain()) // refers to an array of labels from our dataset
  .enter() // creates placeholder
  .append('g') // replace placeholders with g elements
  .attr('class', 'legend') // each g is given a legend class
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                   
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing; // height of element is the height of the colored square plus the spacing      
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2; // vertical offset of the entire legend = height of a single element & half the total number of elements  
    var horz = 18 * legendRectSize; // the legend is shifted to the left to make room for the text
    var vert = i * height - offset; // the top of the element is hifted up or down from the center using the offset defiend earlier and the index of the current element 'i'               
      return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; //return translation       
   });

// adding colored squares to legend
legend.append('rect') // append rectangle squares to legend                                   
  .attr('width', legendRectSize) // width of rect size is defined above                        
  .attr('height', legendRectSize) // height of rect size is defined above                      
  .style('fill', color) // each fill is passed a color
  .style('stroke', color) // each stroke is passed a color
  .on('click', function(label) {
    var rect = d3.select(this); // this refers to the colored squared just clicked
    var enabled = true; // set enabled true to default
    var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) { // can't disable all options
      return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0; // return 1 for each enabled entry. and summing it up
    }));

    if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { // if class is disabled
      rect.attr('class', ''); // remove class disabled
    } else { // else
      if (totalEnabled < 2) return; // if less than two labels are flagged, exit
      rect.attr('class', 'disabled'); // otherwise flag the square disabled
      enabled = false; // set enabled to false
    }

    pie.value(function(d) { 
      if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled; // if entry label matches legend label
        return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; // update enabled property and return count or 0 based on the entry's status
    });

    path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // update pie with new data

    path.transition() // transition of redrawn pie
      .duration(750) // 
      .attrTween('d', function(d) { // 'd' specifies the d attribute that we'll be animating
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // this = current path element
        this._current = interpolate(0); // interpolate between current value and the new value of 'd'
        return function(t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
      });
  });

// adding text to legend
legend.append('text')                                    
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; }); // return label
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>

    <!--Lib css-->
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--fontawesome-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--own css-->
    <style>
        @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

        body {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            background: #fafafa;
        }

        p {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.7em;
            color: #999;
        }

        a,
        a:hover,
        a:focus {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 15px 10px;
            background: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .navbar-btn {
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: none !important;
            border: none;
        }


        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        #sidebar {
            min-width: 250px;
            max-width: 250px;
            background: rgb(60, 95, 238);
            color: #fff;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        #sidebar.active {
            margin-left: -250px;
        }

        #sidebar .sidebar-header {
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgb(90, 121, 243);
        }

        #sidebar ul.components {
            padding: 20px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
        }

        #sidebar ul p {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            display: block;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #sidebar ul li.active>a,
        a[aria-expanded="true"] {
            color: #fff;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 20px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        ul ul a {
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            padding-left: 30px !important;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        ul.CTAs {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        ul.CTAs a {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        a.download {
            background: #fff;
            color: #7386D5;
        }

        a.article,
        a.article:hover {
            background: #6d7fcc !important;
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        #content {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            #sidebar {
                margin-left: -250px;
            }

            #sidebar.active {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

            #sidebarCollapse span {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CHART STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- 

        body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.title-holder {
  text-align: center;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.font {
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* legend */
        .title-holder {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }

        .subtitle {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .font {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .legend {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        rect {
            cursor: pointer;
            stroke-width: 2;
        }

        rect.disabled {
            fill: transparent !important;
        }

        /* chart */
        #pieChart {
            height: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 1200px;
        }

        /* tooltip */
        .tooltip {
            background: #eee;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
            color: #333;
            display: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            left: 130px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            top: 95px;
            width: 80px;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .footer {
            padding-top: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!--lib js-->

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--fontawesome js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

    <!--d3(chart) js-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/">DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--End of nav.sidebar-->
        </nav>

        <!--Page content-->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!--End of div.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="title-holder">
                            <h1 class="title">Language Use in India</h1>
                            <p class="subtitle">Calculated in the Millions</p>
                            <p class="font">Uncheck labels to recalculate.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="pieChart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <footer>
                            <ul class="footer">
                                <li><a href="http://www.censusindia.gov.in/Census_Data_2001/Census_Data_Online/Language/Statement5.aspx"
                                        target="_blank">Data Source</a></li>
                                <li><a href="www.lisaofalltrades.com" target="_blank">lisaofalltrades.com</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
        </div>


    </div>
    <!--End of div.content-->

    </div>
    <!--End of div.wrapper-->

    <!--Lib <script>-->


    <!--own <script>-->

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I've researched on how to use the `d3.schemeCategorry20c` it seems there is no problem in the way I used it. What could be the problem?

Comment: There is no `d3.schemeCategory20` in D3 v5 anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);` to `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);` and error should be gone for you

There is no more schemeCategory20c in d3.v5